# Google script: How to convert google spreadsheet to pdf with few conditions

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to figure this out for last 2 days and I can't seem to do it.
I want to create a script so that I can convert the google spreadsheet into a pdf file, which I have succeed in.
But I would like to automatically save the pdf file as the value contained in cell C6, which I can't seem to figure out.
This is what I have so far which lets me convert it to pdf and save the file into a google drive folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function generatePdf() {

var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var sourcesheet = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("DWTN OFFICE");
var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A1:I58');  
var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
var data = sourcesheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("C6"); 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = sourcesheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
var destrange = sheet.getRange('A1:I58');
destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdf);

var folderID = "1vPvvFNvNLO05ikOdxfl7RPMRE6lvdnJv"; 
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  

}
```

Comment: You need the save the file with the name of the C6 cell? or you need to save the value of C6 in the PDF?

Comment: I would like to name the saved pdf file as the value in cell C6.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the value of the cell:

```
var c6 = sheet.getRange('C6');
```

Then create a file with a name:

```
var newFile = folder.createFile(c6,theBlob);
```

Ref:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename-content